# Como impedir que se agregue un guion bajo "_" al final del contenido de un TextBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando con nicks (nombres de pila).

Cuando un usuario se registra, debe ingresar su nick, el mismo, no puede contener símbolos (exceptuando el guion bajo), solo números y letras.

Hago uso del evento `KeyPress` de mi `TextBox` Username para esto:

```
private void Username_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar)) this.Handled = false;
    else
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '\b') this.Handled = false; //Tecla de borrado
        else
        {
           if (e.KeyChar == '_' && !((TextBox)sender).Text.Contains("_") && ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length > 0) this.Handled = false;
            else this.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    e.Handled = Handled;
}
```

Esta pieza de código impide que se escriban símbolos (diferentes de " _ "), que el contenido inicie con "_" y que se use más de un guion bajo " H_O_L_A ", pero me falta impedir que el guion bajo se pueda usar al final, es decir:

Permitir: Hol_a

Impedir: Hola_

Como puedo conseguir esto?

Comment: No hay forma de saber que el guion es el ultimo caracter que el usuario va a ingresar.  Ese tipo de verification lo tendrias que hacer despues que el usuario ingresa el username completo

Comment: Tienes que hacer esa comprobación al perder el foco ya que al estar escribiendo no vas a saber si es el último carácter o no, o eso o al pulsar enter para comprobar si el usuario y pass son correctos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí tienes una posible solución:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private string text = string.Empty;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox1.KeyDown += TextBox1OnKeyDown;
    }

    private void TextBox1OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        var ultimoCaracter = ((char)e.KeyCode).ToString();
        var fullText = textBox1.Text + ultimoCaracter;

        if (!CumpleReglaNegocio(fullText)) {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }

    private bool CumpleReglaNegocio(string fullText) {
        return new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z|\d]+$").IsMatch(fullText);
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, el manejar el evento "keydown" solo puede servir en caso tu sistema no se internacionalice en otro idioma cuya formato de caracteres sea diferente a la nuestra, por ejemplo el chino, en el que se pueden presionar 2 o más teclas para representar un solo caracter. Si este no es tu caso, este código te puede funcionar.

Si deseas una solución que cumpla con el caso que comenté arriba, te recomendaría manejarlo con el evento "TextChanged" y define una variable local que guarde el estado previo al cambio para setear el textbox con el valor de esta variable, en caso el texto ingresado no cumpla con tu regla de negocio.

Espero te haya ayudado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te puede ayudar a validar si el último valor de la cadena es el guion es agregarle una validación extra a tu código. Me parece que puedes solucionar el problema con el siguiente código:

```
private void Username_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar)) this.Handled = false;
    else
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '\b') this.Handled = false; //Tecla de borrado
        else
        {
           string senderText = (TextBox)sender).Text;
           if (e.KeyChar == '_' 
           && !(senderText.Contains("_") 
               && (senderText.Length > 0
               && (senderText[senderText.Length - 1] != "_")
           ) this.Handled = false;
            else this.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    e.Handled = Handled;
}
```

Comment: Hola Hugo, muchas graias por tu respuesta, ya implementé lo que propones usando `String.Last()` de C# que obtiene el último caracter de un string, y no funcionó

Comment: Me di cuenta de que el error se debe a que KeyPress se ejecuta después de que ya existe un _ al final.

Comment: Podrias modificar el valor después de procesarlo, aunque el usuario lo escriba podrias eliminarlo. También te podria ser mas sencillo que hagas la validación con Javascript y después lo proceses del lado del servidor.

Comment: No uso Javascript en este proyecto, es un proyecto separado de la web